Syncing a tablet to another tablet
I have a DIALN S10 but I don't use it as my main. i use a Lenovo Yoga Tab 13. I want to sync the DIALN tablet with my Lenovo tablet, but it seems the ones that might work either didn't make anything for this situation and just assume that the tablet doesn't have cellular capabilities, or they require a subscription. You guys know anything that would actually help here?

Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There are many things that can be synced, could you [edit] and clarify what you want to sync? This question is tagged with SMS, did you mean you want to sync the SMS only to a non-mobile tablet?
